# Coger valor de select multiple con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un select múltiple del que necesito comprobar el valor con jquery. Necesito saber como se coge el valor de ese select, pues si está vacío me devuelve esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al meterlo en un `if ([] === $("#comercial_lista_calc").val())` me devuelve `false`y si pongo `!==` tampoco funciona correctamente porque no entra en el if.

```
<label for="comercial_lista_calc">{{ "Comercial"|trans }}</label><br>
        <select id="comercial_lista_calc" name="comercial_lista_calc[]" class="chosen selectMed" multiple="true">
            <option value="todos">{{ "Todos.comerciales"|trans }}</option>
            {% for comercial in comerciales %}
                <option value="{{ comercial.id }}">{{ comercial.username|title }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
```

La solución ha sido esta: `if(0 < $("#comercial_lista_calc").val().length)`

Comment: añade el select que estas usando

Comment: ya está añadido

Comment: Me parece que la comparación `if ([] === $("#comercial_lista_calc").val())` [es problemática](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35749696/5587982). Si quieres comparar si está vacío, basta con que hagas: `if ($("#comercial_lista_calc").val()){... `  Otra cosas que puedes hacer para depurar es un `console.log($("#comercial_lista_calc").val());`

Comment: haciendo el console.log del val del select si está vacío muestra `[]` si tiene contenido muestra `["12","10"]` pero en ambos casos si hago un `if ($('#miselect').val())` o `if ($('#miselect').val() !== [] )` da true con lo que siempre pasa por ese if...

Comment: Lo he solucionado de esta manera: `0 < $("#comercial_lista_calc").val().length`

Answer (score 2):

Podrías ponerlo dentro de un evento `change` y evaluarlo ahí.

```
$("#comercial_lista_calc").on('change', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  // te muestra un array de todos los seleccionados
  console.log(val);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en esta comparación:

<s>`if ([] === $("#comercial_lista_calc").val())`</s>

La cual lo que hace es evaluar si dos objetos son iguales...

Si quieres evaluar si el value está vacío, puedes hacerlo mediante un simple  `if(!valorDelSelect){`   o bien mediante un operador ternario que te permite asignar una variable única según esté vació o no y usar esa variable.

Por ejemplo:

```js
$('#comercial_lista_calc').on('change', function() {
  var selValue = this.value;
  var selStatus = (selValue) ? "Tiene el valor: " + selValue : "Está vacío";
  console.log(selStatus);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="comercial_lista_calc">Lista</label><br>
<select id="comercial_lista_calc" name="comercial_lista_calc[]" class="chosen selectMed" multiple="true">
  <option value="todos">Todos</option>
  <option value="uno">Uno</option>
  <option value="dos">Dos</option>
  <option value="">Vacío</option>

</select>
```